# What is the startup performance impact of having lots of Objective C class methods?

Tags: objective-c

I have some generated code which produces several thousand Objective C class methods (spread out over approximately as many classes). I've heard various claims that having a large number of class methods can impact startup performance, since each one imposes some overhead during classloading, but I've yet to see any concrete documentation of this effect.

Do class methods impose a sufficient overhead that I should try and restructure my code?

Comment: If _you_ don't see a significant problem, there's no significant problem. Also note that the class doesn't load until it is first referred to in _executable code_, so the phenomenon might be spread out over time or, if a class is in fact _never_ referred to, might never arise (depending on how you're using these generated classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-C a class method is just an instance method of the *class object* - class methods have a `self` just like instance methods, in the former it is the class object, in the latter the instance object. So both class & instance methods have to be entered into the internal "method tables".

From this one might deduce that any statement about the number of class methods impacting performance in a way that the number of instance methods does not is unlikely to be credible.

Lots of classes is probably more likely to have an impact of possibly non-negligible magnitude (notice lots of uncertainty in that statement!); but if it ain't broke don't fix it - i.e. are you experiencing a problem?